# PHP Facebook SDK get page post author

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm trying to use the Facebook SDK to determine who posted to a Facebook page, though not having much luck, and I'm probably missing something...

I'm currently using `/{page_id}/feed/` to get the actual feed itself, and using `/{post_id}/` to see if I can get the post author, however, both are coming back as the page.

Is it possible to get the actual end user whom made the post, or will it always show the page name? Are there any additional permissions I need to access this?

I am an admin of the page I'm looking at, so it should be visible as far as I am aware.

**Example**

When managing pages, you can see extra details, eg:

```
My Page Name
Posted by My Name · 10 March at 08:58 · Edited ·
```

Whereas public people would just see:

```
My Page Name
10 March at 08:58
```

Since I am a page admin, there should be a way to get `My Name` out, or whoever made the post

Comment: The fields that exists are listed at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/post . Have you checked them all?

Comment: I can get all of those out, but the name/ID only references the page, not the actual physical poster - added example to question...

Comment: That information is simply not available via API. _“Since I am a page admin, there should be a way to get My Name out, or whoever made the post”_ – no, you will get the page as “owner” of the post, and that’s it.